# How to make a cms admin page to change HTML file without SQL or DataBase?

Tags: php, html, content-management-system

I've Created a website without database, I mean, all source codes are in html files, but I need to setup a page for some of spacific pages that I'll be able to change for example: prices and rates through a cms admin. Is it possible to create a cms admin that when we key in amounts, after the submit , automatically it will be affected to html file that we have set it, and those information will be updated through that cms admin page?

Thanks in advance if you will guide me about it.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You need to save it for later then, or you only have it once (or passed with `post/get`) with a variable.

Look into the file saving methods like `file_put_contents` and file retrieving like `file_get_contents` http://de3.php.net/manual/de/function.file.php.

I do know W3Schools is not that legit on SO, but legit to my University, so look into: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_poll.asp for how they use it...

Comment: Thanks, I need to check it. I think so its good way through FTP connection using php to insert file in server. anyway, thank you.

Comment: Right, if you liked it, check the answer. ;)